# skip columns while using LOAD command mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I have a csv file having 5 columns and i want to load only one out of that, is there a way i can do it. I want to use LOAD statement of MySQL 5.5
Any pointers are welcomed, help would be much appreciated

Comment: This is covered in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the documentation:

> You can also discard an input value by assigning it to a user variable
>   and not assigning the variable to a table column:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt'
  INTO TABLE t1
  (column1, @dummy, column2, @dummy, column3);
```

Comment: I have gone through the documentation, but i have a csv file say - 46,94,43,12 now i want to discard the third column,  LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt'
  INTO TABLE t1("WHAT SHOULD I WRITTE HERE?? THE COLUMN NAMES??)... Thanks for your time Phil..

Comment: `LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt'
  INTO TABLE t1
  (column1, column2, @discard3, column4);`

Answer (score 0):

you can save the csv field value to a variable and assign the variable to the table field.

```
load data infile 'filelocation../file.csv' into 
    table myTable columns terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"'
    escaped by '"' lines terminated by '\n'(@value1,@value2,@discardValue,@value4) 
    set f1=@value1 ,f2=@value2,f3=@value4;
```

Comment: Seems identical to Phil's suggestion, only this longer syntax makes you introduce more variables.